# Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution)

Tags: php, apache, битрикс

Установил битрикс. Штатными средствами проверяю его его на ошибки, выдает ошибку в работе с сокетами. Запускаю в php командной строке такой код

```
ini_set("display_errors", true); 
error_reporting(6135); 
$a = fsockopen ("omspk.dizlab.com", 36180, $b, $c, 5); 
echo $a, $b, $c;
```

Выдает такую ошибку

```
Warning: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /var/www/html/bitrix/modules/main/admin/php_command_line.php(138) : eval()'d code on line 3
```

Warning: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /var/www/html/bitrix/modules/main/admin/php_command_line.php(138) : eval()'d code on line 3

```
Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to omspk.dizlab.com:36180 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution) in /var/www/html/bitrix/modules/main/admin/php_command_line.php(138) : eval()'d code on line 3 
0php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Как решить проблему? Сайт работает не по 80 порту, а домен:36180

Comment: Вы хоть в переводчик загоняли текст ошибки? Смотрели, что там в `php_command_line.php` на 3 строке? Вы спрашиваете как решить проблему, но проблема до конца неизвестна.  Что у вас в `$b` и `$c` переменных,  какие параметры должна принять функция `fsockopen`?

Comment: Я думаю что проблема в ДНСах